# Is there any way to automatically convert annotations to XML-mappings

Tags: java, hibernate

I think annotations are easier to read while XML-mappings are laid out more clearly because are not scattered through java-/class-files. So is there a way to convert the annotations from the .java-files into XML-mapping-files?

Comment: What annotations are you speaking of?  Edit your question and include some sample code.

Comment: Hibernate-annotations!